# ANDROID - ERRO: Unchecked cast: java.lang.object to java.util.vector

Tags: android, vector

Estou tentando preencher uma `spinner` de cidade de acordo com o estado selecionado em outra `spinner` via `webservice`.

Porem esta dando um erro nessa linha na classe `usuarioDAO`.

```
Vector<SoapObject> resposta = (Vector<SoapObject>) envelope.getResponse();
```

Erro:

> Unchecked cast: java.lang.object to java.util.vector

Ai minha variável lista esta vindo `null`, acredito que seja por esse erro.

Answer (score 1):

Verifique antes se o retorno do método é do tipo `Vector`, pois o compilador está acusando que você está fazendo uma conversão direta sem verificar antes o tipo do retorno.

```
    if (envelope.getResponse() instanceof Vector) {
        Vector<SoapObject> resposta = (Vector<SoapObject>) envelope.getResponse();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloca o `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`em cima da declaração, dessa forma:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Vector<SoapObject> resposta = (Vector<SoapObject>) envelope.getResponse();
```

Caso não resolva, avisa a gente aqui.

abraços.

Comment: Leonardo, o erro sumiu, porem a Array Lista continua vindo null. Eu acho que é porque estou querendo popular uma array com um vetor. Vou postar aqui o codigo completo do webservice, o cidadeDAO e o Activity que popula a spinner ok?

Answer (score 0):

Galera consegui.

Mudei de ArrayList para somente Array ai consegui popula-lo com o vetor. Muito obrigado a todos.